# Handmade decorators in Ruby on Rails. When Drapper causes more problems than solves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, draper

I'm using Draper gem in my Rails project to obtain decorator pattern functionality. I thought that gem will help to increase my productivity by separating model logic and view logic.

But overall workflow has become terrifying. I should always add `.decorate` to the model in every controller.

My decorators classes are a net of `delegate_all` between each other. Also when I started to use `ActiveModel Serializers`, I had figured that serializers can't work with my decorators.

I don't like this approach and decided not to use a separate decorator class, but provide a Decorator Module for each model.

Is it OK? What problems could arise with this solution?

```
module UserDecorator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  
  included do
    def full_name
      "{first_name} #{last_name}"
    end
  end
end
```

First of all, it's very simple. And I solve the next problems:

1. I don't need to work with decorated inherited class of model. I just provide decorator methods for the existing model class.
2. `ActiveSerializer` can now use decorator methods.

But I feel that something is wrong with this solution. Please, give me some critics!

Answer (score 2):

Either way works.

Using an included decorator concern on those models that share those concerns is fine.

Using a decorator class for each model that needs decorating is also fine.

The code doesn't "smell" right when you say that you "always add `.decorate` to [each] model in every controller".  The README on the Draper gem says that you should defer decoration as late as possible; that is, within the view.

You *can* pass a decoration from the controller to the corresponding view, but you can also pass the original, undecorated object, and let the view choose when decorations are needed.  Just because you *can* decorate every object doesn't mean you should.

Having decorator classes with a "net of delegate_all between each other" (with cross-model decorations) also do not have a good "code smell".

It is fairly common to have a parent class decorator make reference to associated object decorations; that's just good OO design.  Eg:

```
report = Report.where("date < ?", selected_date)
report.decorate
report.line_items.decorate
```

However, if you end up having a lot of common decorations shared across many models, DRYing up your code suggests using a common decorator somewhere -- either in a parent decorator class, or in a shared model concern.

I don't think you should be trying to serialize a decoration; the serialization should be occurring on the model itself.  Alternatively, use a distinct decoration for the attributes that require special-case serialization.